# Create a loop to record next record time and date (based on unique id) in same row

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to create a loop and a if/else statement to pull the next row's timing to record it as timeout. In the event if there is no next row (i.e. no car id#) to return as end/exit.
[Data and envisioned output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFaHk.png)

Here is my code but it doesnt work at all probably not getting the fundamentals right.

```
for(i in 1:dim(df2)[1]){
  if(df2$car.id[i] == df2$car.id[i +1]){
    return$timein[i+1]
  }else{
    print("end")
  } 
    }
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don’t use images of data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. [For multiple reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You’re more likely to get a positive response if your question is reproducible. [See Stack Overflow question guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) paste the output of `dput(df2)` or a sample of your data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Several notes below, but up front try this:

```r
df2$Timeout <- ave(df2$Timein, df2$car.id, FUN = function(z) c(z[-1], NA))
```

The above code returns the next value of `df2$Timein` *per `df2$car.id`*, properly resetting when the next row is a different `car.id`. The order matters, so if you need the `Timein` sorted, then you should sort it before calling `ave(.)`. (This will deal correctly with `car.id` being out of order and even mixed.)

Issues with your (image of) code. If the above doesn't work, you'll need to clarify these points.

1. `nrow(df2)` is the more canonical method than `dim(df2)[1]`.
2. Instead of `nrow(.)`, though, I recommend `for (i in seq_len(nrow(df2)))`, as it behaves better in at least one corner case.
3. Your `[i+1]` indexing will go beyond the index limit and return NA, which will eventually error with `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`.
4. `return$timein[i+1]` seems wrong, unless you have a named-list or `data.frame` object that is `return`; I discourage that, as it can be confused (by people) with the base R primitive (function) `return(.)`. If it is not an object, then you are using it wrong, and frankly I don't know what it should be since a for loop here seems unnecessary.
5. Your expected output is not fully clear, but I'll guess that you want either a timestamp or the literal `"End"`. The latter will break your timestamps, converting them from `POSIXt`-class objects to strings. In general, a column in a frame cannot be mixed classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dplyr`. Working with toy data.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% group_by( car.id ) %>% 
  mutate( Timeout=lead(as.character(Timein), default="END") ) %>% ungroup
# A tibble: 10 x 4
      car.id car.type Timein              Timeout            
       <dbl>    <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>              
 1  14359825        1 2021-12-18 17:28:58 2021-12-18 17:33:58
 2  14359825        1 2021-12-18 17:33:58 2021-12-18 18:03:58
 3  14359825        1 2021-12-18 18:03:58 2021-12-18 18:08:58
 4  14359825        1 2021-12-18 18:08:58 2021-12-18 18:13:58
 5  14359825        1 2021-12-18 18:13:58 END                
 6 243095743        2 2021-12-18 18:30:38 2021-12-18 18:37:18
 7 243095743        2 2021-12-18 18:37:18 2021-12-18 19:17:18
 8 243095743        2 2021-12-18 19:17:18 2021-12-18 19:23:58
 9 243095743        2 2021-12-18 19:23:58 2021-12-18 19:30:38
10 243095743        2 2021-12-18 19:30:38 END
```

If you want a date-only `Timeout` column you can always recast

```
as.POSIXct( dat$Timeout, format="%F %T" )
 [1] "2021-12-18 17:33:58 CET" "2021-12-18 18:03:58 CET"
 [3] "2021-12-18 18:08:58 CET" "2021-12-18 18:13:58 CET"
 [5] NA                        "2021-12-18 18:37:18 CET"
 [7] "2021-12-18 19:17:18 CET" "2021-12-18 19:23:58 CET"
 [9] "2021-12-18 19:30:38 CET" NA
```

or directly use

```
dat %>% group_by( car.id ) %>% mutate( Timeout=lead( Timein ) )
```

##### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(car.id = c(14359825, 14359825, 14359825, 14359825, 
14359825, 243095743, 243095743, 243095743, 243095743, 243095743
), car.type = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Timein = structure(c(1639844938.6685, 
1639845238.6685, 1639847038.6685, 1639847338.6685, 1639847638.6685, 
1639848638.6685, 1639849038.6685, 1639851438.6685, 1639851838.6685, 
1639852238.6685), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: FYI, if `Timein` is `POSIXt`, then with this solution, `Timout` will be `character`. Not a problem if `Timein` is a string vector to begin with.

Comment: @r2evans Yep, I made the decision to silently cast to character to match the desired output. But your probably right to mention that cast somewhere...